# PlayOnLinux displays weird looking window on 18.04 for MS Office installation

Tags: 18.04, graphics, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

PlayOnLinux used to work just fine with 16.04. After upgrading to 18.04 I cannot install MS office from it. After I select the setup and click on install this window pops up:

For approximately 3 seconds it shows this image

[image: first image]

And then suddenly the image disappears and the window looks like this

[image: second image]

When I try installing the software without PlayOnLinux using `wine setup.exe` I get the proper window look:

[image: actual image]

But eventually installation fails and I get this message:

[image: wine error]

Am I missing some essential package/software for rendering the graphics in PlayOnLinux?

This does not allow me to install MS Office using any method, I'm stuck.

Please do not suggest using LibreOffice or Virtual Box. I know both are great alternatives but I would appreciate a solution for this specific problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bug in the MS Office install script or particular wine version / used library.

You can have a workaround: After you created a drive go to options with highlighted virtual drive and hit **Open a shell** button.

From that shell window run `wine setup.exe` and see if your window renders correctly.

PlayOnLinux downloads and uses an older wine version for its Word 2010 setup by default and your system may have a different wine version which can cause the graphics to load incorrectly, try to change it in the settings of your virtual drive in `PlayOnLinux` from `configure` -> `Office2010` -> `General` -> `Wine version`

Comment: I get this error: `Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.`

Comment: I downloaded it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetype/ . How do I add it in PlayOnLinux / Wine? I have no idea please help

Comment: No use winetricks to install corefonts to your virtual drive: download winetricks from github and run in your shell window in your virtual drive: /path/to/winetricks corefonts.

Comment: Also check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/846961/wine-cannot-find-the-freetype-font-library

Comment: Yes your last line is true  indeed. PlayOnLinux downloads and uses wine 1.9.0 for its default Word 2010 setup and my system had version 3.0 which caused the graphics incompatibility problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the same like this....

1) Playonlinux - wine manager - 86x - install wine 3.8

2) Create new 32 bit virtual drive with wine 3.8

***Note:** If you getting error while creating virtual drive; then

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt install wine32

then try to create 32 bit virtual drive again*

3) In that virtual drive - pol component setup - install riched20, dotnet20 & msxml6

4) Install ms office 2010 setup from "non listed" option. (Do not install from the given list)