# PlayOnLinux not detecting FreeType fonts - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wine, fonts, playonlinux

Just started with PlayOnLinux - Tried to install few apps and every time I get some sort of variation of this:

```
10/11/18 12:16:38 - [POL_Wine] Message: Running wine-1.6.2 /home/callmebob/Downloads/setup_fallout2_2.1.0.18.exe POL_GoG_install (Working directory : /home/callmebob/.PlayOnLinux/tmp)
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
http://www.freetype.org
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
http://www.freetype.org
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c057 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c057 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c057 00000001
```

However on my system:

```
callmebob@callmebob-XPS:~$ sudo dpkg -l | grep freetype
ii  libfreetype6:amd64                         2.8.1-2ubuntu2
ii  libfreetype6:i386                          2.8.1-2ubuntu2
ii  libfreetype6-dev:amd64                     2.8.1-2ubuntu2
```

I don't know much about POL, but from what I read their forum it looks to me it may be a common problem on Ubuntu 18.04. I was wondering if anybody knows how to sort this out?

Comment: This may have [already been answered here](https://askubuntu.com/q/846961/411468). One of the people had problems with a single game after this, but maybe they didn't use apt/apt-get/etc to make sure there's no broken dependencies, or maybe they should've used purge rather than remove to nuke the config along with the install data.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing libfreetype6

```
sudo apt purge libfreetype6:i386
sudo apt install libfreetype6:i386
```

source:
https://forums.lutris.net/t/solved-wine-missing-freetype-library/2772

Answer (score 0):

Open PlayonLinux.

Click on your program.

On the right hand side is now a menu, click on configure.

Once the Configuration window is open, go to the "install components" tab.

Scroll until you see "Microsoft Core Fonts"

Install that.

That might help.

Part of your issue might be that you're using wine-1.6.2. PeppermintOS 11 uses wine-3.0, and I Had to switch to Debian 12 recently, because wine-3.0 stopped working with my programs entirely. The reason for that is wine-8.0 is the latest, and 3.0 is REALLY REALLY OLD. 1.6.2 probably can't run anything you're trying to run because the firmware on Ubuntu and Duvian Distros have been neglected for so long, that they are incompatible with newer versions of wine and playonlinux. The Components are no longer compatible with wine, so wine needs updated. If you can't update wine through apt, try https://winehq.org. If you can't update from there, you have no choice but to switch distros to a more modern one in order to use wine. Ubuntu 22.04(Jammy Jellyfish) seems to be the oldest Ubuntu that's compatible with wine 8.0.

Hope this helps. Good luck.