# Problem installing Internet Explorer 8 with PlayOnLinux

Tags: 18.04, wine, playonlinux

PlayOnLinux starts fine. When I select Internet Explorer 8 for installation, the virtual disk is created, but then it hangs, just before the installation wizard begins. A new window is created in the dock, but when maximized it shows nothing but a vertical line.

I found this in the log:

```
Wine cannot find the FreeType font library.  To enable Wine to
use TrueType fonts please install a version of FreeType greater than
or equal to 2.0.5.
http://www.freetype.org
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do what the message says, [install freetype font lib](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/06/install-freetype-2-8-in-ubuntu-16-04-17-04/) .

Comment: I already have.

Comment: Possible [duplicate of this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846961/wine-cannot-find-the-freetype-font-library)